# Westell router setup page

Tags: router, connection

I can connect to the internet, ping 192.168.1.1 with no problem, haven't changed any firewall or Anti-virus settings, but bringing up 192.168.1.1 in the browser gives 'Problem loading page'.  XP machine...was able to connect to the setup page few weeks ago.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you configured it to use `https`.  I know I've done this before a forgotten about it.

Try:  https://192.168.1.1

Comment: that didn't work either